# Generalized Hermite Function as eigenfunction of a differential operator

Tags: python, scipy

I'm going through this [paper](http://inmabb.criba.edu.ar/revuma/pdf/v54n1/v54n1a08.pdf).

The article defines function function $\phi_n^\mu(x)$ that is orthonormal on $L^2$ with measure $dm = dx$:
\begin{equation}
 \phi^\mu_n =\left(\frac{\gamma_\mu(n)}{\Gamma(\mu+\frac{1}{2})}\right)^\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}n!}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}H^\mu_n(x)x^\mu;  \mu,n\in{N},
\end{equation}

Also, it defines differential operator (one-dimensional case, $d=1$, $\mu_1=\mu$)

\begin{equation} \label{eq:hcal}
 \mathcal{H_\mu} = \frac{1}{2}\left( 
   \sum^d_{k=1}\left[
    \mathcal{D}^2_{\mu_k}-\frac{2\mu_k}{x} \left(
     \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\mu_k-1
    \right)
   \right] -|x|^2 
 \right),
\end{equation}
where \begin{equation} \label{eq:dunkl}
 \mathcal{D}_\mu\phi(x)=\phi'(x) + \frac{\mu}{x}\left(
  \phi(x)-\phi(-x)
 \right),
\end{equation}

It is said (in the paper) that $\phi$ is the eigenfunction of $\mathcal{H}^\mu$ operator, i.e. $-2(\mathcal{H}^\mu \phi_n^\mu) (x) = 2(n+\mu+1/2)\phi_n^\mu(x)$ for one-dimensional case.

I have the functions written in Python: dunkl2 for $\mathcal{D}_\mu$, and calh for $\mathcal{H}_\mu$ operator:

```
def dunkl2(n,m,func,x): 
return misc.derivative(func,x,0.001,2) + 2*m*(misc.derivative(func,x,0.001))/x - m*(func(x)-func(-x))/x**2

def calh(n,m,func,x):
return -dunkl2(n,m,lambda x: func(n,m,x),x) + 2*m/x*misc.derivative(lambda x: func(n,m,x),x,0.001) + (2*m/x*(m-1)+x**2)*func(n,m,x)

for i in range(0,10):
print("n =", i, "; m =", 10-i, "; x =", 1, "; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) =", calh(i,10-i,phi,1)/phi(i,10-i,1)
```

I test my Python functions by simply dividing both sides of the differential equation by $\phi_n^\mu(x)$ and checking if the result is $2(n+\mu+1/2)$, and this gives me the set of numbers below. But, as you can see, there's something wrong, at least because the resulting coefficient depends not only on $n$ and $\mu$, but on $x$ also.

Where is my mistake? I can assure you that this phi I use is indeed orthonormal.

Data:

```
n = 0 ; m = 9 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 108.999910168
n = 1 ; m = 8 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 74.9999101676
n = 2 ; m = 7 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 75.0000086295
n = 3 ; m = 6 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 49.0000086295
n = 4 ; m = 5 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 49.0000089668
n = 5 ; m = 4 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 31.0000089668
n = 6 ; m = 3 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 30.9999828753
n = 7 ; m = 2 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 20.9999828754
n = 8 ; m = 1 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 20.9999722442
n = 9 ; m = 0 ; x = 1 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 18.9999722445

n = 0 ; m = 9 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 77.5000026668
n = 1 ; m = 8 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 61.0000026667
n = 2 ; m = 7 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 53.9999972207
n = 3 ; m = 6 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 41.4999972198
n = 4 ; m = 5 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 36.5000043004
n = 5 ; m = 4 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 28.0000043004
n = 6 ; m = 3 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 24.9999862338
n = 7 ; m = 2 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 20.4999862334
n = 8 ; m = 1 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 19.4999826454
n = 9 ; m = 0 ; x = 2 ; (Cal.H * f)(x) / f(x) = 18.9999826456
```

Comment: Where is $k$ inside the sum inside $H_\mu$?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. This question seems to be more a math question than computational science. Nevertheless, I don't understand your question. Are you asking why some functions don't satisfy the orthogonality? If that's the case, why do you want to check this condition numerically? And, what are the functions that you are using?

Comment: to Kirill: my case is one-dimensional, so the sum contains only one element.

Comment: Discretizations of eigenfunctions need not be eigenvectors of the discretized operator. Also, your functions for $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ don't seem to quite correspond to the formulas you gave; you might wish to check them separately (e.g., implement $\mathcal{D}$ and apply it twice to check $\mathcal{D}^2$).